# Join 3 regular expressions in 1

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

everybody.
Could you give me some suggestions on how I can join the following 3 regular expressions in 1?

```
preg_match_all('/&gt;\s*([\w-]+)\s*&lt;/', $str, $matches_1);
preg_match_all('/&lt;\?=\s*([\w-]+)\s*\?&gt;/', $str, $matches_2);
preg_match_all('/echo\s*[&quot;|&#039;]+\s*([\w-]+)[&quot;|&#039;]+/', $str, $matches_3);
```

**UPDATE**

```
preg_match_all(
    '/
       &gt;\s*([\w-]+)\s*&lt;
       |
       &lt;\?=\s*([\w-]+)\s*\?&gt;
       |
       echo\s*(&quot;|&#039;)+\s*([\w-]+)(&quot;|&#039;)+
    /x',
    $str, $matches_123);
```

For me, the syntax above works only if written in one line and removing x-modifier. For some reason, not doing so causes:

Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 125 in ...

I've solved it by just splitting regex in 3 strings and concatenating them but it's a mess.

Comment: One question: does it work?  If so, why fix something that isn't broken?

Comment: @mellamokb It works. But consider you have a really large string, which you need to apply regex to. With code above you will need to parse this large string three times which I believe is not a good practice.

Comment: As @AlanMoore wrote below, that particular 3-line /x regex only worked with each `#` escaped as `\#`. But of course, compacting it again works the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join them as alternatives using `|`

```
preg_match_all(
    '/
       &gt;\s*([\w-]+)\s*&lt;
       |
       &lt;\?=\s*([\w-]+)\s*\?&gt;
       |
       echo\s*(&quot;|&\#039;)+\s*([\w-]+)(&quot;|&\#039;)+
    /x',
    $str, $matches_123);
```

You might want to enclose each part into `(` parens `)` to get them separated in the result list. But then the other subexpressions might need to be `?:` prefixed. Also the alternatives `[&quot;|&#039;]` were invalid (square brackets don't work this way, might function by accident, but isn't a reliable match).

Comment: Thank you, but in my case square brackets really work the way I need. You should have put 'x' before closing quote, too.

Comment: @noname So the last regex is really supposed to match `echo &;abc|#` - because that's what your character class does.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's invalid. I followed your advice. See my question update, plz.

Comment: In `/x` or free-spacing mode, an unescaped `#` marks the beginning of a comment.  That third alternative in your regex is effectively just `echo\s*(&quot;|&`

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by joining... Do you mean "match this, else that, else last"? If so:

```
/&gt;\s*([\w-]+)\s*&lt;|&lt;\?=\s*([\w-]+)\s*\?&gt;|echo\s*(?:&quot;|&#039;)+\s*([\w-]+)(?:&quot;|&#039;)+/
```

Comment: You need to change both instances of `[&quot;|&#039;]` to `(?:&quot;|&#039;)`; that was an error in the original regex.